# Radical of $I = (xy-x^3, y^2-yx^2)$

Tags: commutative-algebra, radicals

> Quick question about finding $\sqrt I$, for $I = (xy-x^3, y^2-yx^2) \subset k[x,y]$.

Attempt:

Using for $I, J$ ideals we have $\sqrt{IJ} = \sqrt I \cap \sqrt J$.

$\sqrt{(xy-x^3, y^2-yx^2)} = \sqrt{(x(y-x^2), y(y-x^2))} =$

$= \sqrt{x, y(y-x^2)}  \cap \sqrt{(y-x^2), y(y-x^2)} =$

$= \sqrt{x, y} \cap \sqrt{x,(y-x^2)} \cap \sqrt{(y-x^2), y} \cap \sqrt{(y-x^2)} =$

$= (x, y) \cap (x,y-x^2) \cap (y-x^2, y) \cap (y-x^2) = $

$= (y-x^2)$

Is there a quicker way to do this? E.g. can one conclude something from the fact that $V(I) = V(\sqrt I)$?

Comment: Why don't use $I=(x,y)$ and $J=(y-x^2)$? Both are prime and the radical is obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Slightly shorter*: the radical of an ideal is the intersection of the prime ideals which contain it. So, determine the prime ideals which contain $xy-x^3$ and $y^2-yx^2$. It is not hard to see there are exactly $2$: the prime ideal $\;(y-x^2)$ and the maximal ideal $\;(x,y)$, which contains the latter. So the radical is $(y-x^2)$.

Comment: Is there any reference for the fact mentioned? Maybe I can conclude this from the intersection for radicals and note that a prime ideal is radical to see this.

Comment: You can deduce it very simply  from the characterisation  of the nilradical of a ring as the intersection of all prime ideals of the ring. See, for instance, Atiyah-Macdonald, *Introduction to commutative Algebra*, prop. 1.8, p.5.